# COD/BAR files to Uplaad a blackberry application in Blackberry app world?

Tags: blackberry, release

I am new to Blackberry Development. I have created one application using Momentics. New I want to upload this application on Blackberry appworld. I have created a [vender account](https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do). Also I have added the product description of my app.

Now I am trying yo upload my release. Now in Step4(Release Details) It is asking to for a **ZIP file containing directories which encompass your COD/BAR files and define your File Bundles you can import it here. Otherwise, you will have to manually add all COD/BAR files and bundles.**. But in my application I did not found a .bar or .cod file. Where I can get this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For build application follow below step..

- In the IDE, click File > Export .
- Expand BlackBerry Tablet OS, select Release Build, and then click
  Next.
- On the Release Build page, select the project you want to export, and
  specify an export location for your application. If you do not
  specify a location, the application is exported to the project
  directory. Click Next.
- On the Digital Signature tab on the Packaging Settings page, select
  Enable digital signature and click Finish

For more infromation you can also check [blackberry documentation.](http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/native/documentation/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/sign_your_app_from_ide.html)